# validates with :if condition failed in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

Having a rfq model in the app. There are two fields. One is need_report which is a boolean. Another one is report_language which is a string. The logic is if need_report is true, then there should be an entry in report_language. Otherwise, if need_report if false, report_language could be empty. Here is the code in rfq.rb:

```
  validates :need_report, :presence => true
  validates_inclusion_of :need_report, :in => [true, false]  
  validates :report_language, :presence => {:if => :need_report?}

  def need_report?
    need_report
  end
```

However the following rspec case failed:

```
  it "should be OK for nil report_language if need_report is false" do
    rfq = Factory.build(:rfq, :need_report => false, :report_language => nil)
    rfq.should be_valid    
  end
```

The error is that the rfq is not valid:

```
  1) Rfq should be OK for nil report_language if need_report is false
     Failure/Error: rfq.should be_valid
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/rfq_spec.rb:57:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This case could pass if "validates :need_report, :presence => true" is removed from the model. It seems that if need_report is true, then report_language can not be empty.

Any thoughts about the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `validates_presence_of` or `validates :column, :presence => true` to check if boolean columns are empty.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of

**Answer:** Instead you need to use `validates_inclusion_of` and specify an array of accepted inputs, which you already have. This should be sufficient validation for what you want to do.

**Explanation:** Your first validation is seeing `false` in the column (which, in Ruby is equivalent to `nil`). It then runs `.blank?` on `nil` and gets back `true` (`false == nil` & `nil.blank? == true`), meaning it thinks the column is blank and it throws an error.

Comment: The problem is caused by that false is actually a nil. So it would failed validates :need_report, :presence => true and make the record not valid.

Comment: exactly. so you can get rid of the first validation and the second one will serve the purpose you need.

Comment: I have to let go validation of need_report field. One way to patch is to set default value in db. I personally don't like false and nil equivalency. Nil is a status which could mean there is no input and it is not the same as false.

Comment: I have edited my answer to be more direct, but that was my initial recommendation. I'd appreciate an accept.

Comment: You got it! Any suggestion to check if a boolean field has an input? I am not saying set the default in db.

Comment: well that's what your validation is doing, but it's doing it at the database level. If you wanted to try to check the input before you save, you could have a javascript function that checks the value of the field before it onsubmit